# Cannot install gem march_hare

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, jruby

I tried adding this to my Gemfile:

```
gem 'march_hare', '~> 2.22'
```

Using `bundle install` I got this message:

```
Could not find gem 'march_hare (~> 2.22)' in any of the gem sources listed in
your Gemfile or available on this machine.
```

On the topmost line in my Gemfile, I have this :

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
```

When I manually visit the rubygems and I m able to find this gem here :

https://rubygems.org/gems/march_hare

How do I install this gem? I don't understand what is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work with any jRuby older than 9.0, this was a miss on my part